# wildfly: how can I static content to appear on top of deployment?

Tags: html, redirect, wildfly, geoserver

I have a geoserver application running within a wildfly server. There is a specific endpoint I want to redirect to another endpoint to hide sensitive information. Specifically whenever a user visits https://localhost/geoserver it should redirect them to https://localhost/geoserver/web.

The strategy to implement this redirection is by creating static content -> an html file containing a meta tag I can use to serve as a redirect. Here is the code in my standalone.xml.

```
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <location name="/geoserver" handler="sub.war"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
                <file name="sub.war" path="/usr/local/something.ear/sub.war" directory-listing="true"/>
            </handlers>
```

The issue is, whenever a user visits the /geoserver url, since that is a url in the deployed geoserver application it ignores the static content and just goes straight to the /geoserver endpoint in geoserver itself.

I have tried switching the location name to something that isn't on /geoserver and it does work as intended, but when it's at /geoserver it just gets ignored because i am assuming the deployment has higher priority. Is there a way to change the priority so that the static content gets checked before the geoserver deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Add your redirect page inside your sub.war

P.s if you just name your sub.war geoserver.war and place in your deployments directory. No need to edit the server config file